# Do all parallelizable manifolds admit a flat metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

A simply connected manifold $M$ admits a flat metric/connection if and only if $M$ is parallelizable.

What happens/can happen if $M$ is notsimply-connected?

Definitions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space

Answer (score 3):

Your assertion is not true, the 3-sphere $S^3$ is a Lie group so it is parallelizable but it does not admits a flat metric, since compact manifolds which admit a flat metric are finitely covered by the n-torus $T^n$.

Comment: Lie groups certainly *do* admit a flat connection. But it will not be torsion-free.

Comment: A flat connection is not a flat metric since it is not necessarily associated to  a metric. For example Levi Civita connection are torsion free. The fact that compact manifod with a flat metric are covered by an $n$-torus is the  Bieberbach theorem.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand. (I spent a career in differential geometry.) The wording of the question, however, referred to a flat metric/connection, as opposed specifically to a flat metric connection. So I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Each parallelizable $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ admits a flat affine connection on $TM$ (the trivial connection). This, of course, does not yield a flat metric. However, if you have a connected noncompact parallelizable manifold (no need to assume simply connected), it does admit a (typically incomplete) flat Riemannian metric. This is an application of the Hirsch-Smale immersion theory: Find an immersion $M\to R^n$ and pull-back the flat metric. On another hand, if $M$ is simply connected and $TM$ has a flat affine connection, then $M$ is indeed parallelizable. (If the connection is complete, then even more is true: $M$ is diffeomorphic to $R^n$.)